# Jquery conditional statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to wrote my script for onepageweb nav. Main goal was to change selector on click and first part is working fine but first li is site logo so when I click on logo I want add `.select` second  li. :

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $(".main-nav li").click(function () {
        if (this = $(".main-nav li:first-of-type")) {
            $(this).next().addClass("selected")
                    .siblings().removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected")
                    .siblings().removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

and this condition not work

Comment: *"first part work fine"* No it doesn't. If you click the element, you'll get an error, look in the web console. You can't assign to `this`.

Comment: `this` is an object.. To compare objects, compare any of the unique property of the object...

Comment: you can check the index of the element, see jquery index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You're using `=` for comparison (`if (this = $(".main-nav li:first-of-type"))`). `=` is always *assignment*. Since you can't assign to `this`, that's an error and nothing else will happen.
2. If you were using `==` or `===` there, it wouldn't work, because `this` will refer to a DOM element, but the return value of `$()` is always a jQuery object.

You may want

```
if ($(this).is(".main-nav li:first-of-type"))
```

...which uses [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) to test if the clicked element matches the given selector.

Side note: `:first-of-type` should work, but because `ul` elements can **only** contain `li` elements, `:first` would work as well.

Live Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".main-nav li").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(".main-nav li:first-of-type")) {
            $(this).next().addClass("selected")
                .siblings().removeClass("selected");
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("selected")
                .siblings().removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav">
  <li>The logo item</li>
  <li>The second item</li>
  <li>The third item</li>
<ul>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not recommended but `this == $(".main-nav li:first-of-type").get(0)` could be used to test as well...

Comment: @Rayon: Yup, or `[0]` rather than `.get(0)`.